# Confusing numbers when extruding

Tags: extrude, dimensions

Suppose I have a cube such as this:

[image: Dimensions]

This is a cube of 10x10x10 cm.
I go into Edit Mode to extrude and then:

[image: Transform]

It says 1.27m but the cube isn't that high even after the extrude it wouldn't be this high. I guessed that maybe this is just 1.27 times the height of the cube but visually it doesn't look like it's 27% taller so I figured that's not the answer.

I thus have two/three questions.

**What are these numbers?** It obviously isn't the height of the original cube and it also obviously isn't the height the cube would have AFTER extrusion.

**How do I extrude to a certain height/depth/width?**. Say my cube is 10cm high, then I extrude this straight upwards to 15cm then rotate that top surface by a few degree and extrude at an angle and I want to extrude it to exactly 20cm height (such that the final structure is exactly 20cm tall).

**How do I extrude to a certain amount in the direction of extrusion?** Similar scenario but unlike extruding to exactly 20cm height I want to extrude 5cm into the extrusion direction (in which case the total height would be less than 20cm).

I also have a few side questions because I'm a beginner but that are unrelated to the problem I have but why does scale change with dimension? If the cube is 0.1m and the scale is 0.05 then it'd be 5e-3 and not 0.1m?

Comment: You have scaled your cube. Either you have to consider this in your calculations or apply the scale.

Comment: But I didn't intend to scale it. I just changed the dimensions of the cube and the scale changed with it. But I saw there's a lock there so I'm assuming I have to lock the scale before changing the cubes size then.

Comment: No that doesn't work. Even if you lock the scale the scale still changes when you alter the dimensions.

Comment: Locking is used to prevent a change to the property. Applying the scale is done by using Ctrl + A > Scale. I can write a full answer if this solves your problem. However, this has already been explained as part of plenty other answers on this website. I just haven't found a good fit that is a direct duplicate, otherwise I would've linked the answer.

Comment: About *"How do I extrude to a certain amount in the direction of extrusion?"*: You can set the exact value in the popup dialog that appears after the extrude operation. Press F9 if you dismissed it and want to have it back.